# GStreamer / Qt. Can't stream to ip I need

Tags: qt, video, qml, video-streaming, gstreamer

For test I send a video via 127.0.0.1 ip and it works:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=1 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=10001`

But when I set a specific ip, it doesn't want to receive it.

If I try to receive a video from terminal, it writes an error:

`bind failed: Error binding to address 192.168.0.152:10001: Cannot assign requested address`

I don't understand what's going on and what's the problem.

P.S: I'm a noob with gstreamer and maybe I do something wrong.

if it's necessary, I've tested an ip for an availability and it wasn't busy

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send to an host with following IP 192.168.10.10 :

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=1 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true ! rtph264pay config-interval=2 ! udpsink host=192.168.0.152 port=10001
```

Receiver side :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://192.168.0.152:10001 caps="application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found that the problem was in Qt on Raspberry Pi